# Django models many to many relationship problem

Tags: html, python-3.x, django

I'm writing my very first django app, kind of cookery book. I have a problem with
showing grammage of ingredient in recipe details view (Ingredient and Recipe are in many-to-many relationship through IngredientRecipe model). Here are my models:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    glycemic_index = models.IntegerField(choices=GLYCEMIC_INDEX)


class Recipe(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cooking_time = models.IntegerField()
    difficulty_level = models.IntegerField(choices=DIFFICULTY_LEVELS, default=1)
    description = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    cuisine = models.ForeignKey('Cuisine', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    ingredient = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, through='IngredientRecipe')


class IngredientRecipe(models.Model):
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    **grammage = models.IntegerField(help_text='in grams')**
```

Here is the view:

```
class RecipeDetailsView(View):
    def get(self, request, id):
        recipe = Recipe.objects.get(id=id)
        ingredients = recipe.ingredient.all()
        return render(request, 'recipe_details.html', {'recipe': recipe, 'ingredients': ingredients})
```

The thing is that currently my view is showing recipe ingredients without their grammage (grammage field in many to many model). I don't know how to put in in my view's code. Tried few different ways but it doesn't work.

Any ideas how to solve it very aprecciated.

And sorry for any mistakes, this is my 1st post in here :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try not using `through` and instead, directing your `ingredient` manytomany field to your `IngredientRecipe` model. This way, the `Recipe.ingredient` will access your `IngredientRecipe` model and you will have the grammage.

if you also need your view to return the name of the ingredient, you can change the `__str()__` method of your `IngredientRecipe` model.

Here's an example of how you could do this:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cooking_time = models.IntegerField()
    difficulty_level = models.IntegerField(choices=DIFFICULTY_LEVELS, default=1)
    description = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    cuisine = models.ForeignKey('Cuisine', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    ingredient = models.ManyToManyField(IngredientRecipe)


class IngredientRecipe(models.Model):
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    grammage = models.IntegerField(help_text='in grams')

    def __str__(self):
        return "CHANGE THIS STRING TO SHOW WHAT YOU WANT TO GET FROM RENDERING THE INGREDIENT FIELD."
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. The thing is there are some rules in my project and i should do it using "through" model